# Seeding parent/child data in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

A Set contains a List of Cards.  A Card contains a List of Sides.  I'd like to seed a bunch of Sets withe a bunch of Cards, each with a couple Sides.  This is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
   context.Sets.AddOrUpdate(s => s.Name,
       new Set()
       {
         Name = "Set "+ i.ToString(),
         Cards = new List<Card>()
            {
             new Card()
               {
                 DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                 IsReady = true,
                 Stage = 0,
                 Sides = new List<Side>()
                     {
                      new Side()
                        {
                          Content = "Blank Side 1"
                        },
                         new Side()
                        {
                          Content = "Blank Side 2" 
                        }
                      }
                  }
               }    
           }        
       );    
   }
```

I'm a little confused about how to handle the foreign keys... how can I set Card.SetID, or Side.CardID, in the above?

Answer (score 1):

Given the format that you're doing it in, you don't need to worry about the FKs. Those should automatically be handled for you by Entity Framework (assuming that your `Set` object has an ID that is Database Generated).